# My register button cant submit but the login is ok in PHP+AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

i am having issue with my registration page in PHP and AJAX, the login section seems to be working fine because i can sign in, but on the registeration button looks disable or dead, cant submit the form. 
i think i make a mistake in some part so am unable to figure out where the problem can be.

**Login:**
this is the login code that can be submit in the login section.

```
    <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="loginBtn">Sign In </button>
     </div>
      </div> 


        <?php require_once("inc/jscript_section.php"); ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("loginBtn").addEventListener("click", submitLogin);
            function submitLogin(){
                var username = password = '';

                username = document.getElementById("usern").value;
                password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;

                if ((username === '' || password === '')){
                    window.location.assign("sign-in.php?m="+'None of the Fields must be empty!');
                } else{
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            if (this.responseText === '1'){
                                window.location.assign("dashboard/index.php");                              
                            }else{
                                window.location.assign("sign-in.php?m="+'Login Failed!');
                            }

                        }
                    };

                    xmlhttp.open("POST","dashboard/ajax/submitlogin.php",true);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xmlhttp.send("password="+password+"&username="+username);
                    document.getElementById("loginBtn").disabled = true;
                }
            }
            </script>
```

**Register:**
this is the register code that don't submit but look disable or have a dead link.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="regBtn">Sign Up</button>
 </div>
</div>



<?php require_once("inc/jscript_section.php"); ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("regBtn").addEventListener("click", submitReg);
            function submitReg(){
                var fname = sname = othername = email = phoneno = refid = '';

                fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
                sname = document.getElementById("sname").value;
                othername = document.getElementById("othername").value;
                email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                phoneno = document.getElementById("phoneno").value;
                refid = document.getElementById("refid").value;
                terms = document.getElementById("terms").checked;

                if ((fname === '' || sname === '' || email === '' || phoneno === '' || refid === '' || terms === false)){
                    console.log("No Field should be empty!");
                } else{
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                            //window.location.assign("sign-up.php?m="+ this.responseText);
                            if (this.responseText == '1'){
                                document.getElementById("regResult").innerHTML = "Your registration was successful, check your email to complete the process";                              
                            }else{
                                document.getElementById("regResult").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                            }

                        }
                    };

                    xmlhttp.open("POST","dashboard/ajax/submitreg.php",true);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xmlhttp.send("fname="+fname+"&sname="+sname+"&othername="+othername+"&phoneno="+phoneno+"&email="+email+"&refid="+refid);
                    document.getElementById("regBtn").disabled = true;
                }
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: With your second snippet copy&pasted into a jsfiddle, the button does not “look dead” to begin with. You are explicitly setting it do disabled at the end of your click handler though, so that is probably the reason. Check what the browser console has to say, and debug what exactly is happening inside the function using your browser dev tools.

Comment: i try changing the document.getElementByID("regBtn").disable = true; to enable still the same..... the click now working

Answer (score -1):

i was able to add enable at the document.getElementById("regBtn").enable= true;

```
<?php require_once("inc/jscript_section.php"); ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("regBtn").addEventListener("click", submitReg);
            function submitReg(){
                var fname = sname = othername = email = phoneno = refid = '';

                fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
                sname = document.getElementById("sname").value;
                othername = document.getElementById("othername").value;
                email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                phoneno = document.getElementById("phoneno").value;
                refid = document.getElementById("refid").value;
                terms = document.getElementById("terms").checked;

                if ((fname === '' || sname === '' || email === '' || phoneno === '' || refid === '' || terms === false)){
                    console.log("No Field should be empty!");
                } else{
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                            //window.location.assign("sign-up.php?m="+ this.responseText);
                            if (this.responseText == '1'){
                                document.getElementById("regResult").innerHTML = "Your registration was successful, check your email to complete the process";                              
                            }else{
                                document.getElementById("regResult").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                            }

                        }
                    };

                    xmlhttp.open("POST","dashboard/ajax/submitreg.php",true);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xmlhttp.send("fname="+fname+"&sname="+sname+"&othername="+othername+"&phoneno="+phoneno+"&email="+email+"&refid="+refid);
                    document.getElementById("regBtn").disabled = true;
                }
            }
            </script>
```